# How to setup AWS elastic beanstalk with windows server 2012

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, windows-server-2012

I'm new to AWS setup, and after having put quite a lot of time into researching an easy way to setup an instance on AWS for a .NET application, I finally decided to go with Elastic Beanstalk.

After creating an elastic beanstalk application (sample application), I need to upload my files and DB to that application and access it via an URL.

I haven't found a simple straight forward tutorial showing this. If someone has links to tutorial websites or have got this done, would like you know the process.

I've created a security group and added a keypair. Do i need to access it via SSH and install FTP and so on?

Help is appreciated.

-Adi.

Answer (score 1):

There are some tutorial videos on .NET development and AWS Elastic Beanstalk available from the Amazon Web Services site here:

https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/